# Different definitions of the thick affine flag variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, geometric-representation-theory, flag-varieties

I have seen several different definitions of the so called "thick" affine flag variety associated to an affine Lie algebra, and I am having trouble seeing why they are the same.

Some notations:

- $\mathfrak g$ is a simple Lie algebra over $\mathbb C$,
- $G$ the simply connected algebraic group over $\mathbb C$ with Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$,
- $B \subset G$ is a Borel, $B_- \subset G$ is an opposite Borel,
- $\mathcal O = \mathbb C[[t]]$, $\mathcal K = \mathbb C((t))$,
- $\hat {\mathfrak g}$ is the affine Lie algebra,
- $I_+ \subset G(\mathcal O)$ is the Iwahoric subgroup over $B$,
- $I_- \subset G(\mathbb C[t^{-1}])$ is the "opposite Iwahoric" subgroup over $B_-$,
- $P_+$ is dominant integral weight lattice of $\hat{\mathfrak g}$

The "thick" flag variety $X$ can be defined as

1. (Kashiwara '89) Consider $G_\infty := \operatorname{Spec} \big( \bigoplus_{\lambda \in P_+} L(\lambda) \otimes L(-\lambda) \big)$, where $L(\lambda)$ is the irreducible module of $\hat{\mathfrak g}$ with highest weight $\lambda$. Then consider a certain subscheme $\mathcal G \subset G_\infty$ which admits a locally free right action of $I_-$. One then defines $X := \mathcal G/I_-$.
2. (Kashiwara '89) Consider Grassmannian variety $\operatorname{Grass}(\hat{\mathfrak g})$, and denote by $x_0$ the point corresponding to the subspace of $\hat{\mathfrak g}$ given as the Lie algebra of $I_-$. Then $X := \bigcup_{w \in W_{aff}} w I_+ \cdot x_0 \subset \operatorname{Grass}(\hat{\mathfrak g})$.
3. $X := G(\mathcal K)/I_-$.
4. $X$ is the stack of $G$-bundles on $\mathbb P^1$ together with a trivialization near $\infty \in \mathbb P^1$ (I am unable to confidently reproduce the definition).

Kashiwara showed that 1. and 2. are equivalent. I have seen remarks in papers saying that the equivalence between 1. and 4. is a consequence of the Drinfeld-Simpson theorem, but I have failed to see how.

My questions are:

> a) **Are all these definitions equivalent? If yes, is the comparison written down somewhere?**

> b) From the construction, it seems to me that the quotient in 1. does not require a sheafification. **Does the quotient in 3. require a sheafification?**

Thanks in advance!